# Need to Modify a MySQL Query to Not to Allow Duplicates Entries into a Table

Tags: mysql, duplicates

First of all I am very new to MySQL and I trying to learn it as I go.

I have a script that runs on page load that retrieves syndicated type data and adds it to a MySQL database table.

All I want to do is add the new data found to the database table without adding duplicates found from a previous page load.

My database table is as follows:

```
// Creates a Database Table only if the Table does not already exist
        mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TableName(
          id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          PRIMARY KEY (id),
          Field_2    varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
          Post_Date  int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
          Field_4    varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
          Field_5    varchar(12) NOT NULL default '',
          Field_6    longtext NOT NULL default '',
          Field_7    longtext NOT NULL default '',
          Field_8    longtext NOT NULL default '') ") or die(mysql_error()
        );
```

There is a single index as shown below:

```
Action     Keyname  Type  Unique Packed Column Cardinality Collation Null Comment
Edit Drop  PRIMARY  BTREE Yes    No     id     830         A
```

The **Post_Date** field is always unique (UNIX format), so it can be used in determining duplicates.

I am currently using the following code to enter the data into the database table and then remove the duplicates:

```
// Enter the $sql Data into the MySQL Database Table
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO $TableName (id, Field_2, Post_Date, Field_4, Field_5, Field_6, Field_7, Field_8) VALUES ".implode(',', $sql));
// Removes Duplicates from the MySQL Database Table based on the 'Post_Date' field
     mysql_query("Alter IGNORE table $TableName add unique key (Post_Date)");
// Deletes the added index key created by the Removes Duplicates function
     mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $TableName DROP INDEX Post_Date");
```

The problem is that the DROP INDEX query fails if the webpage is hit to many times and results in many indexes being created.

Although I have a solution to remove the additional indexes, I was told by other users to avoid this method entirely and try another method similar to INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

But I don't know how to construct the query to make it work.

I did my research and found the following webpage that states how to enter data into a table without duplicates: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm

The webpage states this example:

```
mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO person_tbl (last_name, first_name) -> VALUES( 'Jay', 'Thomas');
```

but I don't know how to modify my query code to make it work.

I tried adding IGNORE to the query, but it also allowed duplicate entries into the table:

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO $TableName (id, Field_2, Post_Date, Field_4, Field_5, Field_6, Field_7, Field_8) VALUES ".implode(',', $sql));
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your unique Index to prevent duplicate records and do your insert queries with adding ignore keyword for not getting errors (if your insert is duplicate) says that documantation and you could do that.

> The presence of a unique index in a table normally causes an error to
>   occur if you insert a record into the table that duplicates an
>   existing record in the column or columns that define the index.
>
> Use INSERT IGNORE rather than INSERT. If a record doesn't duplicate an
>   existing record, MySQL inserts it as usual. If the record is a
>   duplicate, the IGNORE keyword tells MySQL to discard it silently
>   without generating an error.

Edit:

Check sample at sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ad8a/3

Edit2:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable(
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Field_2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `Post_Date` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Field_4` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `Field_5` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `Field_6` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `Field_7` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `Field_8` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Post_Date` (`Post_Date`)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding IGNORE as stated in the post, but it failed. How would I modify the following query code to do it?: mysql_query("INSERT INTO $TableName (id, Field_2, Post_Date, Field_4, Field_5, Field_6, Field_7, Field_8) VALUES ".implode(',', $sql));

Comment: As I wrote  always have to keep unique Index. Ignore just ignores the error if you got a unique Index error. If you don't have unique index you dont get error. I created your sampleo table and sample queries at sqlfiddle. You can check and test there. Check the link I provided on my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But isn't this the same as my added IGNORE line which did not work? mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO $TableName (id, Field_2, Post_Date, Field_4, Field_5, Field_6, Field_7, Field_8) VALUES ".implode(',', $sql)); I am using an implode for the values too. How would I make this line of code work?

Comment: It is not clear what isn't working you are trying to say? I copied your tabel structure and your queries to to sql fiddle, and showed you a working example. Your questions anwer and solution is ready at sqlfiddle.com example. If you still have problem, it is cleaely you are missing something or not giving enough information.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I think I need to add another index called Post_Date to make it work.

Comment: Thats I am telling from start. You need to have a unique index on Post_data always without deleting that index everytime.

Comment: Thanks, It seems to work. I am new to MySQL so I didn't quite understand what you meant. Since the script contains mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TableName(.... Is there a way to add the Alter IGNORE table $TableName add unique key (Post_Date); to the script were it will be bypassed on subsequent page loads and not add another index?

Comment: off course, you can create indexes while creating table. I edited my answer with modifed table schema. And don't forget to accept correct answers for your questions to keep you accept ratio balanced.

Comment: THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH, Last question, do I still need to keep the primary ID index since I added the Post_Date index? The ID column is just sequential numbers.